# How to use PCollection<PubsubMessage> as a sideinput in Beam?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub, apache-beam-io, beam

I am working on a Beam (Dataflow) pipeline, where the task is to read the messages from pubsub and then perform some transformations.
In case there are some failures in any of these transformations I want to send message to the dead letter queue.

Flow looks something like this

```java
// read from pubsub
PCollection<PubsubMessage> message =  p.apply("Read", PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromSubscription('subscription_name'));

// Transformation1

// Transformation2

// Save
```

The `message` is the input to transformation1 and the output of `Transformation1` is input to `Transformation2`.
I am able to send the original `message` to dead letter queue if there is any exception in `Transformation1`. The problem comes when I try to do the same in case `Transformation2` fails.

My requirement is that I have to send the original message back even when `Transformation2` fails.
Is there a way to do it?

in `Transformation2` I tried using `sideInput`, like this:

```java
PCollectionView<List<PubsubMessage>> messageView = message.apply((View.asList())); <-- error
PCollection<TableRow> valid_table_rows = transformation1_Result.apply("Transformation2", ParDo.of(new transformation2()).withSideInputs(messageView));
```

But at runtime this gives me an error:

```java
[2023-05-18, 16:17:52 EDT] {beam.py:127} WARNING - Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GroupByKey cannot be applied to non-bounded PCollection in the GlobalWindow without a trigger. Use a Window.into or Window.triggering transform prior to GroupByKey.
```

The idea is that how can I send the original message to dead letter queue, regardless of which transformation fails.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not perfect but I think you have to transfer your initial message in each step and transformations.

You have to be carreful with `Serialisation` if you are using `SerializableCoder`, if you can't pass the `PubSubMessage` in a Serialisable object.

You can create an intermediate object containing the same fields as `PubSubMessage` :

```java
public class InputMessage implements Serializable {
    private ByteString key;
    private ByteString data;
}
```

Then transfer this message in each transformation

Example :

```java
class YourObject {
   private InputMessage message;

   // other fields.
}

pipeline
   .apply("Map", MapElements.into(of(YourObject.class)).via(Class::yourTransform))


public YourObject yourTransform(final PubSubMessage message) {
        // Apply your different transformations.
         
        InputMessage message = new InputMessage(message.getKey(), message.getData())
        yourObject.setMessage(message);

        return yourObject;
    }
```

Then in the catch bloc, side output and `TupleTag`, you can use the input object.